# What kind of path does move_uploaded_file() require? Absolute or relative?

Tags: php, move

What kind of path does move_uploaded_file() require as destination?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Relative or absolute path? I need to usa relative path as it's more convenient in my case. The file system is Linux.

Comment: Relative path should work.But you have to be sure that relative path is correct.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam It worked fine. Thanks! Had to give 777 permissions to destination folder to make it work.